# How to prevent input values of hour and minute in specific format (hh:mm)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one input field for time entry and it needs to enter hour and minute in `hh:mm` format.  Only numbers can be allowed and additional unnecessary data are restricted.  So could you have some solution for this issue using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) or something that will be OK.  Thank you.

Comment: Be clearer, do you just want to allow numbers and `:`, or do you also want to validate a pattern, i.e (`hh:mm`) etc

Comment: `<input pattern="\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}">`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p18qzkx7/

Comment: @adeneo I want to prevent this format on key down i.e. don't want to allow typing beyond this format.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form>
      <input pattern="\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}" id="Date" required="required" maxlength="5">
      <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Scrpit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Date').keypress(validateNumber);
});

function validateNumber(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (key < 48 || key > 58) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

[See](https://jsfiddle.net/q9c6gdsc/)